# KeyDown, KeyUp and KeyPressed won't fire on a WinForms app hosting a WPF control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, events

I've made a test WinForms APP in C# targeting .NET 4.5. The App uses `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` to draw a white rectangle on a black background.

I've troubles with the keyboard-related events.

Full source is the following

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using Brushes = System.Windows.Media.Brushes;
using Panel = System.Windows.Forms.Panel;
using Rectangle = System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle;
using UserControl = System.Windows.Controls.UserControl;

namespace WpfHostApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Entry point.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var panel = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

            var form = new Form {Size = new Size(800, 600), Text = "WPF Host Form"};
            form.Controls.Add(panel);

            var rectangle = new Rectangle {Fill = Brushes.White, Width = 100, Height = 100};

            var canvas = new Canvas {Background = Brushes.Black};
            canvas.Children.Add(rectangle);

            var userControl = new UserControl {Content = canvas};

            var elementHost = new ElementHost {Child = userControl, Dock = DockStyle.Fill};

            panel.Controls.Add(elementHost);

            form.KeyDown += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("Key pressed!");

            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

The `form.KeyDown` event won't fire (practically `form.Key*` won't fire), but if I comment the line `panel.Controls.Add(elementHost);` the event fires but obviously no canvas is drawn.

I can't see what in the example code above could cause this issue. What could be the culprit?

EDIT:

I've added a recursive function for suscribing KeyDown... no results

In `Main()`, after `form.KeyDown`:

```
foreach (Control control in form.Controls)
{
    SuscribeKeyDown(control);
}
```

`SuscribeKeyDown(Control control)` function:

```
private static void SuscribeKeyDown(Control control)
{
    control.KeyDown += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("Key pressed!");
    foreach (Control controlNested in control.Controls)
    {
        SuscribeKeyDown(controlNested);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is entirely normal, keyboard events are fired on the control with the focus.  That will never be the form.  UserControl and Panel don't want the focus either.  Canvas is happy to take it.  There are plenty of workarounds, none are the obvious best choice since you didn't explain at all why you want these events to fire.

Comment: I've a starfield with parallax scrolling, and I want to kandle key pressing events to change the direction of scrolling. The structure is the same as the example code of this question (with much more happening on canvas object). Also I've tried to `canvas.KeyDown += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("Key pressed!");` and nothing happens

Comment: canvas.KeyDown += (sender, args) => {MessageBox.Show("Key pressed!");}; may be

Comment: @Bit nope, it won't work (just tested)

Comment: @mishamosher I think your brackets.

Comment: @Bit they're not needed, the Lambda expression takes only one instruction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `canvas.Focusable` to `true` and catch the `KeyDown` event of the canvas:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

    var form = new Form { Size = new Size(800, 600), Text = "WPF Host Form" };
    form.Controls.Add(panel);

    var rectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle { Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White, Width = 100, Height = 100 };

    var canvas = new Canvas { Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
        Focusable = true};
    canvas.Children.Add(rectangle);

    var userControl = new System.Windows.Controls.UserControl { Content = canvas };

    var elementHost = new ElementHost { Child = userControl, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

    panel.Controls.Add(elementHost);

    // form.KeyDown += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("Key pressed!");
    canvas.KeyDown += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("Key pressed!");

    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the control is selected and has the focus

```
MyWinformChild.Select();
if(MyWinformChild.Focus())
```

Hook on LostFocus to keep it selected or simply to know when it happens

```
MyWinformChild.LostFocus += MyWinformChild_LostFocus;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the form's `KeyPreview` field to `true`. Then your form's `KeyDown` event will work.

Comment: It won't work, even with recursive KeyDown event suscribing (see EDIT on question)

Comment: Just tried suscribing `form.PreviewKeyDown` (with `KeyPreview` set to `true`). No luck.

Comment: Does anyone know why this doesn't work? I feel like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Add to Form TabControl and put ElementHost to TabPage. And now KeyDown/KeyUp will be work.
Not the best practice, but it works.